# prevent Next Js from Caching and preFretching specific page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, prefetch

I am working on e-commerce website and I am using Next Js and everything was working ok till I Started to work on Cart Page cause its always changing - I am using ssr with it cause I need to do some checks on the server - I found that due to prefetching and caching it show old data on soft Navigation and even when I set cache-control header to no-store Next js keeps storing the cart Page data